# how to add acf value to other plugins shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

Hi I am creating site with ACF and other plugin (WP-Appbox).
WP-Appbox allow me to add little download box of app with shortcode.
shortcode is as follow.
[appbox storename appid].
If I want to show chrome from google store I will add [appbox googleplay com.android.chrome] in post or theme.
so my requirement is how can I manipulate storename value and app id.
with advanced custom field.
ex. 
there will be 2 acf field store-name and app-id 
so I can add those field values from editor to shortcode.
and following code is added in single.php
as of now I came to this.

```
$thestore = get_field('store-name');
$theapp = get_field('app-id');
echo do_shortcode("[appbox $thestore $theapp]");
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding quotes around the values returned by ACF:

```
$thestore = get_field('store-name'); 
$theapp = get_field('app-id'); 
echo do_shortcode('[appbox "' . $thestore . '" "' . $theapp . '"]');
```